# NO GCOV DATA FOUND

Tags: eclipse, testing, gcov

I am using Eclipse Juno with GCC compiler for C code. I am trying to use gcno plugin to get code coverage.

of course I added `-ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs` to the compiler and the linker flags. 
But, when I click on profiling tools for code coverage I get the error in the image below:

> "Recompile at least one of your C/C++ source files with the
>   "-fprofile-arcs" and "-ftest-coverage" options and link your
>   executable with "-lgcov". If you compile and link in a single gcc
>   call, you can use the gcc "--coverage" option. "

Please I need help with this error.

Comment: have checked .gcno files are genarated after compiling?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the gcov code coverage results you must not only compile with the compiler and linker flags you mentions, but you must also either run a unit test or run your program to gather the data. Gcov gathers the data as the points in your code are reached. If you do not run the program you will not generate any data.

Comment: Correct. Running generates the .gcno and .gcda files. Note that coverage is cumulative. If a line is executed one per run and you run twice, its count will be two. Delete those files to reset the counters. Note that the makefile generated by Eclipse will **not** remove them when you `make clean`